# IP prefixes/subnet sorting more specific IP address

Tags: python

I m new to python and i m trying to below ask for my project.
Ask:
I want to keep only more specific prefixes in each set.

```
SetA: 1.1.1.0/24 ; 2.0.0.0/8 ; 3.3.0.0/16 ; 4.4.4.4/32 ; 5.5.5.5/32

SetB: 1.1.1.1/32 ; 2.2.2.0/24 ; 3.0.0.0/8 ; 4.4.0.0/16 ; 6.6.6.6/32

SetC: 1.1.0.0/16 ; 2.2.2.2/32 ; 3.3.3.0/24 ; 4.0.0.0/8 ; 7.7.7.7/32

SetD : 1.0.0.0/8 ; 2.2.0.0/16 ; 3.3.3.3/32 ; 4.4.4.0/24 ; 8.8.8.8/32
```

How I will solve it? Need help. so at the end each set has only more specific IP address.

```
I was thinking this type of the logic.
A>B
B=B 
A = A-B : 1.1.1.0/24 ( except 1.1.1.1/32)

C>A
A=A
C = C-A : 1.1.1.0/16 ( except 1.1.1.0/24)


D>A
A=A
D = D-A : 1.1.1.0/8 ( except 1.1.0.0/16)
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Hi Jaimin, Can you please provide an example of the end output that you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: The `/32` addresses are the most specific, of course.  Are you just hoping to keep the `/32`s in each set?

Comment: Python has standard module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) - maybe it helps.